# Java: Edge cases and future requirements for adding two numbers

Tags: java

Got a interview question to find out edge cases and future requirements for adding two numbers.
**Adding Two Numbers**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("First number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = input.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("Second number: ");
    int b = input.nextInt();  

    int sum = a+b;

    System.out.println("Result: "+sum); 
}
```

**Edge Case 1**
Null Check. Any of the input number could be null.

**Edge Case 2**
Large input numbers.

**Final Program**
Which will be using BigInteger instead of integer.

```
BigInteger first = new BigInteger(number1);
BigInteger second = new BigInteger(number2);
```

Is there any other edge case or future requirement which can be considered here?

Comment: Negative numbers. Zero.

Comment: How would the input numbers become `null`?

Comment: What if the user enter a text?

Comment: You forgot about decimals.

Comment: First question that comes to mind. What kind of numbers? Int, long, float, complex? A ton of stuff to think about.

Comment: May be a better question for [code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Null check and all are sanity check - these will not be part of Edge Cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test case can be divided into two parts :

Sanity Check ( Null or Non-numeric fields) - This is not included in your Edge Case !

Hence your `Edge Case 1` - is not an Edge Case

Your `Edge Case 2` is a valid case but it does not specify whats a BIG Number.

`Now`, you are using primitive type to store values of `Number1` and `Number2` and doing the arithmetic on primitive type. So lets consider only the evaluation of "Primitive Types"

As per definition : `Edge cases are inputs that the specification for your function allows but that might be tricky to handle.` - `Josh Zimmerman`

In my opinion, these are the cases two be considered;

Remember : `The Java virtual machine does not indicate overflow during operations on integer data types.`

```
Overflow Conditions / Information Loss in Arithmetic : (For int, from -2147483648 to 2147483647 (-231 to 231-1), inclusive)

1. Addition of two large negative integer numbers causing an overflow 
2. Addition of two large positive integer number causing an overflow 
3. Addition of two opposite signed numbers 
4. Addition of X =0 and Y=0


Large input where x < MIN INT or > MAX INT on JAVA Platform 

1. Handling LARGE (-/+) numbers as input - can be termed as INFINITE ? How will the system behave ?
```